# Tricky @Field description for RetroFit FormUrlEncoded parameter using a List of Objects

Tags: java, forms, retrofit, url-parameters

I am performing a @POST operation using @FormUrlEncoded, because the API i'm hitting requires HTTP params as input.

The params the target API are expecting to see should look like (simplified):

alist[0][object1]=1&alist[0][object2]=astring&alist[1][object1]=2&alist[2][object2]=bstring

JsonIzed (for clarity) looks like:

```
{ 
  "alist": [
    { 
      "object1" : "1",
      "object2" : "astring"
    },
    { 
      "object1" : "2",
      "object2" : "bstring"
    }
  ]
}
```

So essentially, alist[0][object1] is 1, alist[0][object2] is "astring".

The closest I've gotten is using @FieldMap:

```
...
@FieldMap Map<String,String> myFieldMap
...
```

I have something like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Post("/somewhere")
SearchHandle search(@FieldMap Map<String, String> myMap);
```

Which gets me:

```
{ 
  "alist": {
    "0" : {
        "object1" : "1",
        "object2" : "astring"
    },
    "1" : {
      "object1" : "2",
      "object2" : "bstring"
    }  
  }    
}
```

Which is close - but the API is expecting an Array.  So I need an Array of ... what exactly?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

create a class for modeling your data :

```
class model {
  String object1;
  int object2;
}
```

now your alist should be an array of model objects and you can create json object from your array using Gson or jackson or etc.

Comment: But, it needs to be @FormUrlEncoded - so being a JsonObject doesn't buy me anything?